# numpy ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause

I am trying to design a `np.where`argument which has the below inputs

```
r_label = np.array([['Fiscal data as of Dec 31 2016', '2016', '2015', '2014'],
       ['Fiscal data as of Dec 31 2016', '2016', '2015', '2014']],
        dtype='<U29')

x = pd.Int64Index([12, 12], dtype='int64')

r_values_count = 2

check = np.isnat(pd.to_datetime(r_label[:,1:][0], errors='coerce', format='%b %d %Y')).all()

if_true =  [pd.to_datetime(r_label[:,1:][_], errors='coerce').map(lambda t: t.replace(month=x[_])) for _ in range(r_values_count)]

if_false = [pd.to_datetime(r_label[:,1:][_], errors='coerce', format='%b %d %Y') for _ in range(r_values_count)]

np.where(check, if_true, if_false)
```

but i am getting error  `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`. All the three parameters of `np.where` argument work perfectly well independently, I am not able to understand why it does now work inside `np.where` and how do i find where exactly is the code producing error

Comment: Something is error in if_false. Try replacing `if_false = [pd.to_datetime(r_label[:,1:][_], errors='coerce') for _ in range(r_values_count)]`

Comment: What is the program attempting to do here? Isn't `check` just a `bool` (i.e. not a list), so it will take all of either `if_true` or `if_false`?